# Material.side issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to export model from Blender with transparent backfaces. This is how my mesh looks in Blender (backfaces are not hidden):

[image]

Than I export it with json exporter as a single mesh. Settings screensot:

[image]

And than I use JSONLoader to add mesh to the scene. Result:

[image]

So if I need to make this mesh one-sided I need to use:

```
material.side = THREE.FrontSide;
```

And it works:

[image]

But if I use this exporter settings:

[image]

And than use ObjectLoader to add mesh to the scene:

[image]

As you can see if I export a single object and use JSONLoader I have a mesh with double-sided materials, but if I export all scene and use ObjectLoader I have a mesh with one-sided materials.

It is not the best solution to change material.side to THREE.FrontSide every time. Is there a way to change material.side in Blender or manualy in already exported json file?

Comment: Can you hide the backfaces in blender and try exporting again? Looks to me that the json exporter may not be exporting everything.

Comment: @pailhead I tried [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/UB7bwsMvQKqQlW-RoLeBBA.png) it doesnt help.